# Array of linked lists for hash tables C++

Tags: c++, hash, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a hash function `h(x) = x % 127` as an array of linked lists. Currently I have created an add function where I add new nodes to the linked lists, however I don't understand why nothing is written in any linked list. I'm reading the inputs number from a file and I'm sending it to the linked list as input%127.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
//#define prim 127
using namespace std;

ifstream f("hashuri.in");
ofstream g("hashuri.out");

struct nod {
    int info;
    nod *next;
};

void add_nod(nod *p, nod *&u, int info) {
    if (p == NULL) {
        p = new nod;
        p->info = info;
        u = p;
        u->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        nod *c = new nod;
        c->info = info;
        u->next = c;
        u = c;
        u->next = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nr_op, op, x, prim = 127;
    nod * p[127], *u[127];
    for (int i = 0; i < prim; i++) {
        p[i] = u[i] = NULL;
    }

    f >> nr_op;
    while (!f.eof()) {
        f >> op >> x;
        if (op == 1) {
            //delete_nod(p[x%prim], u[x%prim], x);
        }
        if (op == 2) {
            add_nod(p[x%prim], u[x%prim], x);
        }
        if (op == 3) {
            //search_nod(p[x%prim], u[x%prim], x);
        }
    }

    //printing an array of linked lists
    for (int i = 0; i < prim; i++) {
        if (p[i] != NULL) {
            nod *c;
            c = p[i];
            cout << i << ": ";
            while (c != NULL) {
                cout << c->info << " ";
                c = c->next;
            }
        }
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My input file `permutari.in` contains:

```
7
1 3
1 20
2 7
3 4
3 20
2 20
3 20
```

Comment: You should give your variables more descriptive names. It's difficult to tell what anything is supposed to be with only 1-4 letter names. Stuff like `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)` is usually acceptable because the convention of indexing into collections is well established, but for anything else, give your variables better names.

Comment: What is `p` supposed to be doing? The only thing you do with it in `add_nod` is check whether it’s null—if it is, you store your new node pointer in the same variable; if not you store it in a different variable named `c`, but either way the effect is the same; the only difference is whether you set `u->next` to the new node pointer or not. Since I can’t tell what this code is supposed to be doing or what this variable is supposed to mean, I can’t tell you how to fix it, but I can guess that this is central to your problem.

Comment: Anyway, you never assign anything to any of the `p[i]` values except that initial `NULL`, so when you get to the part whether you loop over them and skip the null values, of course you skip all of them because they’re all null.

Comment: Consider making the linked list a class rather than a collection of functions. Come t think of it, if allowed by whatever assignment has you on this task, strongly consider `using std::list`.